# Change group of a newly created User in PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

Using PyroCMS 2.2, how can I have a registration form assign a user to one of the new Groups I created. Within the admin panel, I have a created a user group called `client`. When my registration form within my module is sent, it creates the client, but sets the type for group to `$config['default_group']       = 'user';` within the core module.

Is there a way for me to set the group to client for this specific registration form in this module?

Comment: Did you try changing it to `$config['default_group'] = 'client';`

Comment: Thats not gonna fix the problem. What if I want to create a new module for subcontractors and so on...which I do eventually. Its not good to change code within core modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this:

- When you redirect the user to the costum registration form, set a session variable with value of your costume module name for example
- Use [PyroCMS events](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/events) (`Events::trigger('post_user_register', $id)`) and build a `events.php` file for your module so that, after every user registration this event will be triggered and since you have set the session variable, you can decide to change the user group of newly created user to an appropriate one and be sure to unset the session variable after you are done.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Where do you put the events.php file? what if you have 1 module and you would like to allow two types of different users to join. Teacher or Student but with the same module.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is an inbuilt way to do this.

```
system/cms/modules/users/controllers/users.php:384

// We are registering with a null group_id so we just
// use the default user ID in the settings.
$id = $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, null, $profile_data);
```

[It also appears it isn't possible to override the core modules](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/issues/1325#issuecomment-7740818).

Seems like you have 2 options:

- Modify the core module
- Try to port the user module into your own module