# Changing user group with post_user_register event

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I don't really understand how events work in PyroCMS. I want to update a user role based on the type of user a person selects during registration. It's quite similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109933/change-group-of-a-newly-created-user-in-pyrocms). Because I don't understand how events work, I don't know how to proceed. This my events class I added in the user module folder:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Events_Users{

```
protected $ci;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();


    Events::register('post_user_register', array($this, 'update_user_group'));
}

public function update_user_group($user_id)
{
    //loading the user model class
    $this->ci->load->model(array('users/user_m'));
    //getting the users details
    $user = $this->ci->user_m->get(array('id' => $user_id));
    //assigning the user type variable
    $user_type = $user->tell_us_who_you_are;
    $set =  array('group_id' => $user_type);        
    if($user_type == 'spectator')
    {
        //do nothing
    }else{
        //update user group
        $this->db->update('users',$set, array('id'=>$user_id));    
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`Events::register('post_user_register', array($id, 'update_user_group'));`

This line registers your custom function to an event, When an event ( here post_user_register ) is called then your function ( here `update_user_group` ) will be triggered.

You just need to change your function name and pass the user_id which will be passed to it by the event trigger.

```
public function update_user_group($user_id)
    {
        // your logic
        //dump($user_id);die();
    }
```

So try this code for your events.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Events_Users{

    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();


        Events::register('post_user_register', array($this, 'update_user_group'));
    }

    public function update_user_group($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->update('users', array('group_id' => $this->input->post('user_type')), array('user_id'=>$user_id));    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I understand better now. After making the necessary changes to your code, I get the following error on submitting the registration form. Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 484

Comment: could you post your code? just edit your question and add it.

Comment: that's the new code, i edited it when i made the comment above.